# PHP CLI: UTF8 problems

Tags: php, utf-8, command-line-interface

I'm writing a PHP CLI-Application; in my application I want to handle some array-to-json-operations.

Let's use an example:

```
$test = array( 'bla' => 'äöü' );
$test['bla'] = htmlentities( $test['bla'] );

echo json_encode( $test );
```

The output is the following:

```
{"bla":"&auml;&ouml;&uuml;"}
```

If I use this to handle my array

```
function encode_items(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
}
array_walk_recursive($rows, 'encode_items');
```

I'm getting stuff like that:

```
2\u20ac
```

What can I do here? I read some stuff about changing the php.ini - do I really have to do that or can I do something in my code to get the stuff working?

Thank you very much :-)

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do in the end, which you have not made clear. If this really "just" about json encoding an error you define in the code, then you do not need stuff like `htmlentities()` or the like. Just make sure your code file is written (saved) in UTF-8 encoding (make _really_ sure, for example by checking with a hexeditor) and use php json encoding function. No specific encoding required, since you have no transport layout to rescue data over or something.

Comment: Hi arkascha,
thank you for your response. The file is saved id UTF-8 (console says: text/x-c++; charset=utf-8). My task: Get information from model (mysql) and work with them. After that use the result (array) and convert it to json. This json has to be stored in another database again; but before it is saved again, there are some things, that are going on with this json: A method of the store-function checks for some keys like "%" and "€" and is calculating with them. These calculations do not work if the json uses 2\u20ac instead of "2€".

Comment: OK, in that case you also have to make sure your database communication is UTF based, so connection, database and table definition and the actual data entered. If that is all fine, then as said: just use `json_encode()` and all should be fine, no need to convert, in contrary, that will only create problems because of multiple conversions.

Comment: About "what encoding is used by json": the answer is: none. json does not define the character encoding at all. json is just a string in whatever encoding it is created. So the `2\u20ac` is an escape sequence created by some prior step of your script, not somehow by json encoding some string (unless done wrong). So stop creating such sequences, stop converting, and you won't have such stuff in your json string.

Comment: Oh, and a last thing: do not trust what you are presented when looking at the data, most visualization actually (try to) interpret the payload, often wrong. Instead to be sure dump the output into a file and then examine that, as said: a hexeditor is the only reliable tool I know for that job (for debugging and _really_ making sure).

Comment: Hi arkascha, i'll have a look at it, but this will take some time. In my array, which should be converted to json the "€" is displayed correctly.

Comment: Hi arkascha... I got some news: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE works fine while encoding. What does this mean for my case? Is it safe to use it?